# A simple TabHost in android

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, android-button

### I have created a simple tab project in Android

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    // TabSpec Names
        private static final String TAB1 = "Tab1";
        private static final String TAB2 = "Tab2";
        private static final String TAB3 = "Tab3";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            // Inbox Tab
            TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB1);
            Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
            inboxSpec.setIndicator(TAB1);
            // Tab Content
            inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

            // Outbox Tab
            TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB2);
            Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
            PriceSpec .setIndicator(TAB2);
            PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);

            // Profile Tab
            TabSpec DistanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB3);
            Intent DistanceIntent = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
            DistanceSpec .setIndicator(TAB3); 
            DistanceSpec.setContent(DistanceIntent);

            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
            tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(PriceSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(DistanceSpec); 

            //Set the current value tab to default first tab
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

            //Setting custom height for the tabs
            final int height = 45;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = height;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = height;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = height;
        }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**OUTPUT** ::

[image]

---

**`How can i make a horizontal set of 5 buttons on top of the tab to get something like this in the below figure`**

[image]

---

What are the code changes i need to make in `main.xml` ?

Comment: You can add any type of layout linear or relative on top of TAB Bar.

Comment: I have tried but, was not able to set the specs right .... can you edit it as your answer .... atleast with 2 buttons .... that will help me to get more clarity , thanks

Comment: Please check my answer. And please give up vote and green mark..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/screen_topbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white" >
            </TabWidget>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And TopBar layout-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Just try this sure it will work..

Comment: Adding a reference from one to another layout .... that was a clear & clean explanation ! .... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Add one more `LinearLayout` define your buttons inside above `TabWidget` and fixed your `FrameLayout` height with weight, look below code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dm_footer_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. Replace your main.xml code with the below code. it will work

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
       <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button android:layout_width="100dp" android:text=" Button 1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     <Button android:layout_width="100dp" android:text=" Button 2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <Button android:layout_width="100dp" android:text=" Button 3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       <Button android:layout_width="100dp" android:text=" Button 4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
<TabHost 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```